# Highlight active tabs in bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bxzvoes7/) of my problem.

Basically, I am using [Bootstrap 3 Tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) and it is working fine. What I am looking to achieve is to activate the tabs using links within the `.tab-content` DIV. Now these links are working fine and activating the correct tabs, but they don't change the `background-color` of `ul.nav-pills`. So the Javascript is not changing the `.active` class of appropriate links. Can anybody guide me to a solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle the Bootstrap `shown.bs.tab` event using jQuery...

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    var hash = $(e.target).attr("href");
    $('.nav a').filter('a[href="'+hash+'"]').tab('show');
});
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/oIJ45JT6lz